# Which is the client side JavaScript framework that is easy on the learner, but provides the evented architecture I need?

Tags: client-side, javascript-framework

A senior dev yesterday told me about the widgets-events-sandbox-mvc architecture (thanks man).

Widgets have Collections, Models, Controllers, Views... and events happening to the views are communicated to other widgets on the page by the sandbox, and it also passes in the required model relevant to that event so that the other widget can take action accordingly.

I am building something very similar to [Zillow's map search](http://www.zillow.com/homes/new-york_rb/), and the "search" area needs to communicate with the "results" area. Plus the "results" widget needs to communicate with Leaflet.js and *stay* in communication from time to time to take action on the maptiles.

I need something that will help me with the events, provide me a sandbox so I don't have to build it myself, gives me a nice way to translate REST returned data into Collections.

I have glanced at Backbone but it needs me to build my own Sandbox, though it's Collections and Events should help me.

Can.js proclaims to be "easy on the learner" but I haven't seen anything resembling a Sandbox there.

My experience level with JS: writing sphagetti jQuery calls on the DOM to do shiny stuff. Haven't ever used RequireJS or its ilk before. I've read and understood Part I of "The Definitive Guide" so I understand the core concepts of JS's Objects. I know "Laravel", which is a Rails-like server side PHP framework.

I'll continue to [look for info](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/) on this, would really appreciate if I can advice considering my experience though.

Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 0):

First think if you really need that.

That pattern is pointless if you don't have to reuse widgets on multiple applications, and will only complicate your entire application.

CanJS resembles classical MVC framework, and doesn't offer sandbox, but you can achieve similar behavior by inheritance, e.g. any controller (or view) can be host to other controllers (widgets) and communicate with them.

If you really are after sandboxed modules, look at [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Comment: I feel it's wrong to dismiss evented widgets are useless unless they are reusable. I need the event architecture for easy communication between the various parts of my page.

Can you please give an example (even pseudocode) of the Controller inheritance simulating Events?

Thanks for the recommendation on Angular, feel free to fill in with more reasons why if you'd like though.